# Нужны ли тире перед "это" (в первом предложении) и "последовать" (во втором)?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Но последовать совету честного коллеги это ниже твоего достоинства, верно?!

Но это же ниже твоего достоинства последовать совету честного коллеги, верно?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *Но последовать совету честного коллеги — это ниже твоего достоинства, верно?!*

(2) *Но это же ниже твоего достоинства — последовать совету честного коллеги, верно?!*

**Тире ставится в обоих предложениях.**

В предложении (1) предикативная основа "последовать — это ниже достоинства". Тире ставится перед связкой ***это***.

В предложении (2) предикативная основа "это ниже достоинства", а инфинитивный оборот раскрывает содержание местоимения ***это*** (в роли подлежащего). Оборот обособляется тире как **присоединительная** конструкция.